# Classic ASP Error Downloading Access Database From Server to Client

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following script in a classic asp page:

```
<%
Response.Write "<script language=""vbscript"">" & vbcrlf
'----------------------------------
Response.Write "sub window_onload" & vbcrlf 
'Response.Write "On Error Resume Next" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "    dim t1 " & vbcrlf
Response.Write "    set xfile = AXFFileDownload.XFRequest " & vbcrlf

Response.Write "    AXFFileDownload.AddFile ""c:\contalfinger\tester.mdb"", ""http://" & Request.servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR") & application("portinternet") & "/transfert_fichiers/FZ" & kteur & ".mdb" & chr(34) & vbcrlf
Response.Write "    If Err.number <> 0 Then " & vbcrlf
Response.Write "        msgbox(""You may not have SA-XFile installed."") " & vbcrlf
Response.Write "    End IF " & vbcrlf
'Response.Write "   call contalMSN.faireDirectory(""c:\contalfinger"") " & vbcrlf   
Response.Write "    t1=contalMSN.wait(2) " & vbcrlf 
Response.write "    AXFFileDownload.Start" & vbcrlf

'Response.Write "   call contalMSN.faireCMD(""c:\tmp\fichier2.eml"") " & vbcrlf
'Response.Write "   window.close() " & vbcrlf
Response.Write "    window.location.href=""loginfinger.asp" & chr(34) & vbcrlf
Response.Write "end sub" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "</script>" & vbcrlf
%>
```

The problem is that the mdb file on the server has 336KB but when it is downloaded to the client computer it's reduce to 2KB and can't be open due to following error message: Unrecorignised database format.
This script was working before we change server.
Any help will be reallly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Are you now using a later version of access than your contalfinger component recognises?

Comment: No, version is the same. But when I open the mdb file in notepad. Here is what I see: <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>

Comment: Searching more, I got the following message: HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

Comment: Can you replace "http: //" & Request.servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR") & application("portinternet") & " with a hardcoded URL where you would expect to find your database

Comment: It is exactly what I did and it returned the following error message: HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

Comment: I missed the obvious.  "configured to deny the file extension".  You need to configure IIS to serve files with the extension .mdb  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it. I had to modify the file found in the below path:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config

```
<add fileExtension=".mdb" allowed="false" /> for <add fileExtension=".mdb" allowed="true" />
```